# Crystal Report IFieldObject

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with IFieldObject. i retrieve  boolean values from database in to IFieldObject.my issue is that i need to print "Submitted" if True else "Not Submitted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Syntax for a formula:

```
If {MyFieldName} Then "Submitted" Else "Not Submitted"
```